# Usage of Perl custom script from shell

Tags: shell, perl

I'm trying to pass a variable to a custom Perl script.

```
        $file="my_wa/fin"
        if [[ "$file" == *"fin" ]]; then
            script.pl 
        fi
```

In my script I try to use `$file` as my path to open and read a file

```
my $input_filename = "$ENV{file}";
```

I understand that I need to export it somehow and receive it in my Perl code,
but it doesn't recognize `$file`. - it works perfectly if I just write `my_wa/fin`.

Comment: try to read alvinalexander.com/perl/perl-command-line-arguments-read-arg‌​s

Comment: @ilux, 404 not found

Comment: oh, https://alvinalexander.com/perl/perl-command-line-arguments-read-args

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass $file as an argument

```
$file="my_wa/fin"
    if [[ "$file" == *"fin" ]]; then
        script.pl \"$file\"
    fi
```

Then access the data

```
my $input_filename = $ARGV[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not export the variable in the shell before calling the perl program.

Paste your shell code into http://www.shellcheck.net/ -- it will tell you your other shell error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to export the environment variable file in your shell before the perl script execution. Also you may want to make sure to include full path to the file.

`export file=/full/path/to/my/file/my_wa/fin`

Or making use of `pwd` if it is relative to current working directory:

`export file="$(pwd)/my_wa/fin"`